# Retrieve records with no matching rows in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have two tables named `doctor` and `patient`

Here is my `doctor` table

[image]

Here is my `patient` table

[image]

First I wanted to retrieve list of doctor IDs together with the number of appointments made for each doctor with one or more appointments

I can do it with below query,

```
Select d.doctor_id, count(p.patient_id)
from patient p, doctor d
where d.doctor_id=p.registered_with
group by d.doctor_id;
```

Result:

[image]

But now I need to modify the previous query to include any doctors with no appointments too (Ex: The doctor with id 51 doesn't have any appointments. I want to include him in the above result)

How can I do this?

PS: If the title is misleading, someone please re-correct it for me

Comment: use *outer join* such as `RIGHT JOIN`. eg `from patient p RIGHT JOIN doctor d ON d.doctor_id=p.registered_with`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `implicit join`
You need to use `left join` as

```
Select 
d.doctor_id, 
coalesce(count(p.patient_id),0) as `patient_count`
from  doctor d
left join patient p on d.doctor_id=p.registered_with
group by d.doctor_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `right outer join`

```
Select d.doctor_id, count(p.patient_id)
from patient p right outer join doctor d
on d.doctor_id=p.registered_with
group by d.doctor_id;
```

Comment: This gives an error, "Syntax error, Unexpected where"

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to comment... 
basically this is slight changed solution of   **abhik-chakraborty**

```
    select 
    d.doctor_id,
    isnull(count(patient_id),0) no_of_appointments
    from doctor d
    left outer join patient p
    on
    p.registered_with = d.doctor_id
    group by d.doctor_id;
```